# Extract data from the json response body

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm making a postman call to an endpoint and i want to save in a variable only a number from my response body's field.

```
POST {{baseURL}}/{{version}}/{{customersEndpoint}}

response:
{
    "firstName": "te",
    "lastName": "test",
    "customerUrl": "/api/v1/customers/172"
}
```

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody)
console.log(response)
console.log(response.customerUrl)
```

I want to save in a variable only the number 172.

```
var customerID = response.customerUrl(something) ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could try parsing it, for example with a simple regex: `response.customerUrl.match("\/[0-9]+")[0]`. It gives "/172", actually, but you can modify it further yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is representative of the expected format of `customerUrl`, you can do:

```
const customerUrlPieces = response.customerUrl.split('/');
const customerID = customerUrlPieces[customerUrlPieces.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the `customerUrl` string, and get just the number.

```js
response= {
    "firstName": "te",
    "lastName": "test",
    "customerUrl": "/api/v1/customers/172"
}

const customerId = response.customerUrl.split("/")[4]

console.log(customerId)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get those numbers by matching them with a RegExp;

```
response.customerUrl.match(/\d{2,}/)[0]
```

\d{2,} will check for 2 or more digits in a row

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Robert, and thank you for your answer. Since this question already has a few other answers, it would be helpful if you can explain the benefit of your answer in relation to the other answers.